# Boost::Log Safety of using the same backend with multiple sinks

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

Mine is not a real problem but more a *correct usage* question.

**Foreword**: I am using boost::log as logging facility and I am working on some libraries that will be shared among different applications and all may need different levels of logging.
I came up with a setup where I have (or may have) specific channels and severity levels for each library, and a kind of factory that enables the library-using application to create the proper/desired sink(s) for the library, without the need of knowing the details of the library's channels and severity levels.

**Now the real question**: wanting to collect all the application's logs in some specific "places" (e.g. stdout, or some severity related files) I was planning to feed all the relevant sinks with the same backend; ***is this approach correct***? I didn't find anything against it in the docs, but neither an example showing this usage...

An example would be:

```
namespace bl = boost::log;
namespace bl_snk = boost::log::sinks;
.
.
.
boost::shared_ptr< bl_snk::text_file_backend > text_backend = boost::make_shared< bl_snk::text_file_backend >(
                bl::keywords::file_name = "/tmp/file_%5N.log",
                bl::keywords::rotation_size = 5 * 1024 * 1024,
                bl::keywords::time_based_rotation = bl_snk::file::rotation_at_time_point(12, 0, 0)
            );
text_backend->auto_flush(true);

log_factory_libA.CreateSink< bl_snk::text_file_backend >(text_backend);
log_factory_libB.CreateSink< bl_snk::text_file_backend >(text_backend);
```

Where, under the hood, CreateSink does basically:

```
using sink_t = bl_snk::synchronous_sink< bl_snk::text_file_backend >;
boost::shared_ptr<sink_t> lib_sink = boost::make_shared<sink_t>(text_backend);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was planning to feed all the relevant sinks with the same backend; is this approach correct?

No, this is not correct. Sink frontends implement thread synchronization, so if multiple frontends share a backend the backend becomes unprotected.

There is generally no reason to use multiple frontends for a single backend. If you want to direct multiple channels to a single file or console, you don't need to create multiple sinks. A single sink should be created per file/console; you can control which channels are routed to the sink by updating its filter.

Comment: I get the point.

My rationale behind this approach was that I wanted to "decouple" the logs from a plugin from the logs in the main application, freeing the main application from the need to know the details of the logging inside the plugin (e.g. the channels or, most relevant, the log severity levels - which in my idea could be different and unique to the plugin).