# boost::log - Using independent severity levels inside a library/plugin

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

This is a kind of follow-up of another question I asked ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47714906/boostlog-safety-of-using-the-same-backend-with-multiple-sinks/47726015#47726015)) where I was made aware that using the same backend with multiple sinks is not a safe approach.

What I am trying to obtain is to "decouple" the severity levels inside a library/plugin from the applications using them, while being able to write the different logs to the same output (may it be stdout or, more likely, a file or a remote logger); this for the following reasons:

1. I wouldn't like to tie the severity levels inside my library/plugin to those of the applications using them because the change (for whatever reason) of the severity levels list in one of the applications using the library/plugin would cause the library to be "updated" with the new severities and, as a waterfall, of all other applications which use the library/plugin
2. I would like to be able to use library specific severity levels (which, for being correctly displayed in the log messaged should be supplied to the sink formatter - thus my need of using different sinks)

**Which is the best way to obtain this?**

*Some afterthoughts*: As per Andrey's reply to my previous question the "problem" is that the backend is not synchronized to receive data from multiple sources (sinks); thus the solution might seem to be to create a synchronized version of the backends (e.g. wrapping the writes to the backend in a boost::asio post)...
***Is this the only solution?***

---

*Edit/Update*

I update the question after Andrey's awesome reply, mainly for sake of completeness: the libraries/plugins are meant to be used with internally developed applications only, thus it is assumed that there will be a common API we can shape for defining the log structure and behaviour.
Plus, most applications are meant to run mainly "unmanned", i.e. with really minimal, if not null, user/runtime interaction, so the basic idea is to have the log level set in some plugin specific configuration file, read at startup (or set to be reloaded upon a specific application API command from the application).

Comment: Why not completely decouple your library from the logging library? IMO a library should not force a particular logging framework upon the users. Users may already have their own framework. I would rather provide a callback from your library which would enable users to forward logging output to their logging library of choice.

Comment: @zett42 Interesting idea, though as this is an internal project and we already use several boost libraries our initial idea is to stick with boost, so in this case boost::log is the desired solution. And for sake of completeness we are planning to substitute an old (internal I guess) logging library with boost::log..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd like to address this premise:

> for being correctly displayed in the log messaged should be supplied to the sink formatter - thus my need of using different sinks

You don't need different sinks to be able to filter or format different types of severity levels. Your filters and formatters have to deal with that, not the sink itself. Only create multiple sinks if you need *multiple log targets*. So to answer your question, you should focus on the protocol of setting up filters and formatters rather than sinks.

The exact way to do that is difficult to suggest because you didn't specify the design of your application/plugin system. What I mean by that is that there must be some common API that must be shared by both the application and the libraries, and the way you set up logging will depend on where that API belongs. Severity levels, among other things, must be a part of that API. For example:

- If you're writing plugins for a specific application (e.g. plugins for a media player) then the application is the one that defines the plugin API, including the severity levels and even possibly the attribute names the plugins must use. The application configures sinks, including filters and formatters, using the attributes mandated by the API, and plugins never do any configuration and only emit log records. Note that the API may include some attributes that allow to distinguish plugins from each other (e.g. a channel name), which would allow the application to process logs from different plugins differently (e.g. write to different files).
- If you're writing both plugins and application(s) to adhere some common API, possibly defined by a third party, then logging protocol must still be defined by that API. If it's not, then you cannot assume that any other application or plugin not written by you supports logging of any kind, even that it uses Boost.Log at all. In this case every plugin and the application itself must deal with logging independently, which is the worst case scenario because the plugins and the application may affect each other in unpredictable ways. It is also difficult to manage the system like that because every component will have to be configured separately by the user.
- If you're writing an application that must be compatible with multiple libraries, each having its own API, then it is the application who should be aware of logging convention taken in each an every library it uses, there's no way around it. This may include setting up callbacks in the libraries, intercepting file output and translating between library's log severity levels and the application severity levels. If the libraries use Boost.Log to emit log records then they should document the attributes they use, including the severity levels, so that the application is able to setup the logging properly.

So, in order to take one approach or the other, you should first decide how your application and plugins interface each other and what API they share and how that API defines logging. The best case scenario is when you define the API, so you can also set the logging conventions you want. In that case, although possible, it is not advisable or typical to have arbitrary severity levels allowed by the API because it significantly complicates implementation and configuration of the system.

However, just in case if for some reason you do need to support arbitrary severity levels and there's no way around that, you can define an API for the library to provide, which can help the application to set up filters and formatters. For example, each plugin can provide API like this:

```
// Returns the filter that the plugin wishes to use for its records
boost::log::filter get_filter();

// The function extracts log severity from the log record
// and converts it to a string
typedef std::function<
    std::string(boost::log::record_view const&)
> severity_formatter;
// Returns the severity formatter, specific for the plugin
severity_formatter get_severity_formatter();
```

Then the application can use a special filter that will make use of this API.

```
struct plugin_filters
{
    std::shared_mutex mutex;
    // Plugin-specific filters
    std::vector< boost::log::filter > filters;
};

// Custom filter
bool check_plugin_filters(
    boost::log::attribute_value_set const& values,
    std::shared_ptr< plugin_filters > const& p)
{
    // Filters can be called in parallel, we need to synchronize
    std::shared_lock< std::shared_mutex > lock(p->mutex);

    for (auto const& f : p->filters)
    {
        // Call each of the plugin's filter and pass the record
        // if any of the filters passes
        if (f(values))
            return true;
    }

    // Suppress the record by default
    return false;
}

std::shared_ptr< plugin_filters > pf = std::make_shared< plugin_filters >();

// Set the filter
sink->set_filter(std::bind(&check_plugin_filters, std::placeholders::_1, pf));

// Add filters from plugins
std::unique_lock< std::shared_mutex > lock(pf->mutex);
pf->filters.push_back(plugin1->get_filter());
pf->filters.push_back(plugin2->get_filter());
...
```

And a similar formatter:

```
struct plugin_formatters
{
    std::shared_mutex mutex;
    // Plugin-specific severity formatters
    std::vector< severity_formatter > severity_formatters;
};

// Custom severity formatter
std::string plugin_severity_formatter(
    boost::log::record_view const& rec,
    std::shared_ptr< plugin_formatters > const& p)
{
    std::shared_lock< std::shared_mutex > lock(p->mutex);

    for (auto const& f : p->severity_formatters)
    {
        // Call each of the plugin's formatter and return the result
        // if any of the formatters is able to extract the severity
        std::string str = f(rec);
        if (!str.empty())
            return str;
    }

    // By default return an empty string
    return std::string();
}

std::shared_ptr< plugin_formatters > pf =
    std::make_shared< plugin_formatters >();

// Set the formatter
sink->set_formatter(
    boost::log::expressions::stream << "["
        << boost::phoenix::bind(&plugin_severity_formatter,
               boost::log::expressions::record, pf)
        << "] " << boost::log::expressions::message);

// Add formatters from plugins
std::unique_lock< std::shared_mutex > lock(pf->mutex);
pf->severity_formatters.push_back(plugin1->get_severity_formatter());
pf->severity_formatters.push_back(plugin2->get_severity_formatter());
...
```

Note, however, that at least with regard to filters, this approach is flawed because you allow the plugins to define the filters. Normally, it should be the application who selects which records are being logged. And for that there must be a way to translate library-specific severity levels to some common, probably defined by the application levels.

Comment: Again thanks for making me aware of my misconception about sink formatters. I wasn't aware (maybe I read the relevant doc too quickly) I could filter the formatter. Anyway, as the severity levels are enums for enabling the app to change the plugin levels, the API could provide the range of its levels and some methods to increase/decrease the currently used level, or set it to some value within the range.

Comment: Just having a range of severity levels is not enough. The severity attribute will use a specific enum type as its value type; without knowing that enum type the application or the logging library will not be able to extract severity level from log records and, subsequently, apply filters or formatters. The API must specify the exact enum type, which should be used by all plugins and the application. Or you could use a simple `int` as the severity level, but then your code will be less descriptive and type-safe.

Comment: *I wasn't aware I could filter the formatter.* I'm not sure I understood you here, you don't "filter" the formatter. The `severity_formatter` in my example is just a function that (a) extracts the severity level of the plugin's enum type from a log record and (b) converts it to a string. If a log record is generated by a different plugin then the severity level attribute will likely have a different either name or type, so (a) will fail and the function will return an empty string. This way only the function of the corresponding plugin will succeed and return the relevant string.

Comment: For the 1st comment: I probably have worded badly my idea: if the API on the plugin side exposes some increase/decrease level methods, the application will be able to "tell" the plugin to modify it filtered level - or knowing the range, the application could tell the plugin "set the filter to the highest/lowest level". I understand this means that after that the application will likely have to reload the plugin filter and replace the one it holds in its vector.

Comment: For the 2nd comment: again I have badly, hastily, worded my thinking... with that phrase I meant I wasn't aware I could use a function inside the formatter, which could be used to filter the messages from the relevant source (what your example does is clear to me)